# Specify python version when creating a new virtual-environment using pyenv-virtualenvwrapper and change the version afterwards

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenvwrapper, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

As far as I've understood, with the *homebrew-installed pyenv-virtualenvwrapper* I can create a new virtual environment via the command `mkvirtualenv proj_name` independently of the current working directory in the terminal where I'm executing the command.
I.e., I assume I don't have to do `cd /path/to/proj_name` before executing `mkvirtualenv proj_name`.

Still, what I was wondering is how to choose the local python version of this very project, since if I used `pyenv virtualenv` the syntax allows for specifying the exact python version for that very project like [so](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/#working-with-multiple-environments):
`pyenv virtualenv 3.9.0 proj_name`

What I did was going into the project folder via `cd /path/to/proj_name` and executed `pyenv local 3.9.0` before creating the virtual environment (venv) via `mkvirtualenv proj_name`, but I'm not sure whether this had an effect at all.

How will the python version for the new project venv created via `pyenv-virtualenvwrapper` be chosen, and can it be changed for that specific venv later on?

---

OS:

Description:    Lubuntu 20.04.1 LTS,
Release:        20.04,
Codename:       focal